# Did Cinda know who Poppy was?

Tags: plot-explanation, only-murders-in-the-building

In the final episode of season 2, it is revealed that…

> Poppy is actually Becky Butler, the missing girl from Oklahoma that Cinda's original podcast is about.

Was it revealed if Cinda knew her true identity? Did I miss something in the show that revealed what Cinda knew? Throughout the episode, it misleads the audience into believing that Cinda was the killer, and that she worked with Poppy on the entire “fake” podcast. Once it is revealed that Poppy is the actual killer, it is not clarified if the parts about Cinda knowing Poppy's identity were part of the false narrative being shown or not.

To clarify, I’m not wondering if she knew Poppy was the murderer; I think that was maid clear (she was informed about that off-camera during the final episode).

Ok with in-universe or out-of-universe answers, if such a thing exists. At the least it would help establish more about her character; was she willing to fake an entire murder mystery for a good podcast?

Comment: I'm no fan of spoilers, but if you can see the spoil before even opening the question, that could be a different matter. I've spoiler-tagged & also shifted the paragraphs around slightly so you get no clue without opening the question.

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m a bit confused, you can’t see any of the body unless you choose to open the question, can you? I did my best to avoid any spoiler in the title. I don’t mind your edit, though.

Comment: Ah, just saw that you can see a preview of the question from the search results page. Got it, thanks!

Comment: It depends how you view the question list. If you use default view you get 'Active', which shows titles only - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6YMd.png If you switch to Newest via the burger menu's Questions - https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3uQb.png then you get the first couple of lines too - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUyYS.png That's my personal default [bookmarked] view for all my SE pages, as I find it much more informative.

Comment: You can see from that view why I also shifted one extra innocuous line up to shove the big plot giveaway off the first couple of lines. As I say, I don't usually like spoiler tags, but I just thought [without knowing the show] that this might just ruin the ending for someone invested in it ;))